# QML GridLayout how to position elements

Tags: qml, qgridlayout

I would like to position elements in a grid layout like in picture 1 and picture 2.

[image]

Picture 1

[image]

Picture 2

I have already tried various examples but I can't get the positioning right. It only seems to work if I fill all cells with dummy content. But even that only works to a limited extent.

Since I have several of these use cases I would like to realise the cell content via a component in this form:

```
       GridLayout { anchors.fill: parent; rows: 4; columns: 4
            GridContent { height: 50; width: 50; p_column: 0; p_row: 2; p_image: "warning" }
            GridContent { height: 50; width: 50; p_column: 0; p_row: 3; p_image: "info.png" }
            GridContent { height: 50; width: 50; p_column: 1; p_row: 2; p_colspan: 2; p_rowspan: 2; p_text: "This is a text over 2 columns and 2 rows" }
         }
```

Is this possible in any form or is a different layout more appropriate?

Comment: You should fill the empty space of the `GridLayout` with something, such as `padding` or empty `Item`. Additionally, please provide more information about the problem you have and the sample you provided.

Comment: You can use a `RowLayout` with `ColumnLayout`

Answer (score 0):

With `GridLayout`, as the items will be arranged according to the `flow` and `layoutDirection` properties, you can't set only the main items, you have to define also the blank items.

In my example below, I have defined the different parts of the grid by using `rowSpan` and `columnSpan` to fill blank spaces with "filler" items. Next, you can easily display your items inside the other areas.

But maybe it is not the best `Layout` for your problem. You could try a combo of `Column/Row` or `ColumnLayout/RowLayout`, as suggested in the comments.

```
GridLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    rows: 4
    columns: 4
    flow: GridLayout.TopToBottom
    rowSpacing: 0
    columnSpacing: 0

    property int cellWidth: width / rows
    property int cellHeight: height / columns

    // Filler
    Rectangle {
        Layout.rowSpan: 2
        Layout.columnSpan: 4
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.cellWidth * Layout.columnSpan
        Layout.preferredHeight: parent.cellHeight * Layout.rowSpan
        border.color: "orange"
        border.width: 1
    }

    // Icon Top
    Rectangle {
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.cellWidth * Layout.columnSpan
        Layout.preferredHeight: parent.cellHeight * Layout.rowSpan
        border.color: "orange"
        border.width: 1

        Image {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: "warning"
        }
    }

    // Icon Bottom
    Rectangle {
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.cellWidth * Layout.columnSpan
        Layout.preferredHeight: parent.cellHeight * Layout.rowSpan
        border.color: "orange"
        border.width: 1

        Image {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: "info.png"
        }
    }

    // Text Area
    Rectangle {
        Layout.rowSpan: 2
        Layout.columnSpan: 2
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.cellWidth * Layout.columnSpan
        Layout.preferredHeight: parent.cellHeight * Layout.rowSpan
        border.color: "orange"
        border.width: 1

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "This is a text over 2 columns and 2 rows"
        }
    }

    // Filler
    Rectangle {
        Layout.rowSpan: 2
        Layout.columnSpan: 1
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.cellWidth * Layout.columnSpan
        Layout.preferredHeight: parent.cellHeight * Layout.rowSpan
        border.color: "orange"
        border.width: 1
    }
}
```